# Rails : Named yield not rendering wit partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering, yield, partial

I am trying to render a partial using a named yield. Here's my template

```
<%= render 'shared/remote_modal', modal_title: "bru" do %>
  <%= content_for(:modal_content) do %>
    <%= render @registrations, show_learner: true, show_product: false %> 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and here's shared/remote_modal :

```
<div class="relative px-4 w-full max-w-6xl md:h-auto">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="relative bg-white rounded-lg shadow dark:bg-gray-700">
    <!-- Modal header -->
    <div class="w-full">
      <div class="flex justify-between items-start p-5 rounded-t">
        <div class="w-full-0">
            <h3 class="text-lg font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
              <%= modal_title %>
            </h3>
        </div>
        <i class="close-modal fas fa-times text-lg cursor-pointer"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal body -->
    <div class="px-6">
      <div class="w-full">
        <%= yield(:modal_content) %> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see shared/remote_modal has `yield(:modal_content)` and my template uses `content_for(:modal_content)`. However the block within content_for(:modal_content) is not rendering.

If I change it to a "simple" "unnamed" yield though, it will render properly. Are named yield not supported with partials ? Is there a workaround to this ?

Answer (score 0):

A possible issue could be that you're using `content_for` inside the partial, which might not work as expected.

Instead, you can try a different approach (not sure if that's the same you already tried). Try passing the content as a block (without using `content_for`), and then render this block inside the partial using a simple `yield`:

```
<%= render 'shared/remote_modal', modal_title: "bru" do %>
  <%= render @registrations, show_learner: true, show_product: false %> 
<% end %>
```

Partial:

```
...
<!-- Modal body -->
<div class="px-6">
  <div class="w-full">
    <%= yield %> 
  </div>
</div>
...
```